# Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $a \in X$. Show that the intersection of all neighborhoods of $a$ is the singleton $\{a\}$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $a \in X$. Show that the intersection of all neighborhoods of $a$ is the singleton $\{a\}$.

Let $b \in X$ and $\varepsilon = |a-b|$. Now since $(a-\varepsilon, a+\varepsilon)$ is a neighborhood of $a$ I have that if $b \in (a-\varepsilon, a+\varepsilon) \Longrightarrow |a-b| < \varepsilon$ which would be a contradiction and would imply that $b$ doesn't belong in the collection of neighborhoods of $a$. What confuses me is that we're talking about general metric spaces and not $\mathbb{R}$, how should this be shown for a general metric space?

Comment: Replace $|a-b|$ with $d(a,b)$ and $(a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon)$ with $B_\epsilon(a) = \{x \in X \mid d(a,x)<\epsilon\}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $b\ne a$, then $b\notin B_{d(a,b)}(a)$. So, for every $b\in X\setminus\{a\}$, there is some neighborhood of $a$ to which $b$ does not belong. In other words, the only point of $X$ which belongs to every  neighborhood of $a$ is $a$ itself.